# dual-monitor on Linux : how to change the virtual resolution of only one screen

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, resolution, xorg, xrandr

I am using Centos 6.3 with two screens :

```
screen A : 1280x1024
screen B : 1680x1050
```

Screen A is the main screen, and screen B an extension. The problem is, screen A should accept a virtual resolution of 1280x1050 instead of 1280x1024.

With only one screen connected to the PC, I run on a terminal :

```
$ xrandr --fb 1280x1050 --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024 --panning 1280x1050
```

And it works, I have my new virtual resolution and I can access the masked parts touching the edge of the screen.

The problem came with two screens. I want like before, to enlarge screen A without touching the resolution of screen B, but the command does not work and I don't know how to do. I tested with

```
$ xrandr --fb <NEW_RES_WITH_TWO_SCREENS>
```

but It makes one big same screen on the two monitors. I read that I should modify the xorg.conf file but it seems that this file does not exist on /etc/X11... when I want to create one :

```
$ Xorg -configure
```

I have an error..

> Fatal server error : Server is already active for display 0, if this
>   server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock and start again

***context*** : I have to run on screen A an appli, which man/machine interface resolution is larger than the screen resolution. And I can't modify the code.

Any help would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

When you want to set up more than one monitor you need to [get their names](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/3edb91846b0d22f4488de989f6c3d60d24db5b92/.screenlayout/monitor_resolutions.sh#L63) and [specify their resolution separately](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/3edb91846b0d22f4488de989f6c3d60d24db5b92/.screenlayout/right-tack.sh#L13):

```
count=0
xrandr --query | while read -r word1 word2 _
do
    if [ "${word2:-}" = 'connected' ]
    then
        IFS='xi ' read -r width height _
        printf '%s %d %d\n' "$word1" "$width" "$height"
    fi
done | while read monitor width height
do
    count=$(($count + 1))
    printf "monitor%d_name='%s'\n" "$count" "$monitor"
    printf "monitor%d_width='%s'\n" "$count" "$width"
    printf "monitor%d_height='%s'\n" "$count" "$height"
done
```

Example output:

```
monitor1_name='LVDS1'
monitor1_width='1366'
monitor1_height='768'
monitor2_name='VGA1'
monitor2_width='1280'
monitor2_height='1024'
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I agree with your post when resolution are known and applicable for the monitor. Correct me if I'm wrong, you suggest this command line :

`xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024 --pos 0x0 --output HDMI1 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 1280x0`

What if I want to change the VGA resolution to 1280x1050 instead of 1280x1024 ?

Comment: I found a trick to get the 1280x1050 resolution for my VGA monitor with `cvt 1280 1050 75` and `xrandr --newmode <...>`.

Then I use it like you said ( @l0b0 ) : `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1050_75 --pos 0x0 --output HDMI1 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 1280x0` and it works but I don't have the ability to scroll and see the masked part of the virtual resolution.. even if I use the `--panning 1280x1050`.